# Prestashop CMS Page has one column layout

Tags: php, smarty, prestashop

I tried googling and reading different tutorials, but still can't figure out why CMS pages on my Prestashop website have only one column.

I need the left template block, I know how to use it in the admin, transplant and work with modules. The thing is I'm stuck with this thing, and I'm pretty sure it's an easy fix.

Anyone?

Thank you!

Comment: You can't set the used template/theme or layout options in the backend in Prestashop? I just know about Magento, where one may select the layout from the backend.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a custom theme? In default theme there is a three column template for CMS pages.

So I assume that you previous developers probably edited your theme and it could be done in three ways (that I know):

1.left column is rendered in header.tpl and right column in footer.tpl

```
{if $page_name != 'cms'}

<div id="right_column" class="column">
{$HOOK_RIGHT_COLUMN}
</div>

{/if}
```

and the same in header.tpl for {$HOOK_LEFT_COLUMN}

2.in your css file they can just set #cms #right_column {display:none;} and #cms #left_column {display:none;}

3.in Modules->Position (in admin panel) you can define Exception field for pages where modules should not be called (but this is not most likely not your case)